# Express - How to get serialize form

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm trying to submit a form with `serialize` but in express I can't obtain the data.

jquery:

```
    function submitSettingsCustom()
   {
     $('#reception-source-custom-form, expedition-source-custom-form').on("submit", function(event)
     {
       alert("works");
       event.preventDefault();
       var form = $(this).serialize();
       $.post("/add-reception-source-customField/"+ JSON.stringify(form), function(data){

       });
     });
   }
```

Route:

```
routes.post('/add-reception-source-customField/:form', settings.storeCustomField);
```

In express I'm trying to `console.log` the array:

```
console.log(req.params.form);
```

That returns this:

```
"name=Emp1&type=submitReceptionSourceCustomFields"
```

But how can access to each value?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your form data as body in post request not inside url

Also `serialize` will result in urlEncoded data, while `serializeArray` will result in array of objects.

```
   function submitSettingsCustom()
   {
     $('#reception-source-custom-form, expedition-source-custom-form').on("submit", function(event)
     {
       alert("works");
       event.preventDefault();
       var form = $(this).serializeArray();
       $.post("/add-reception-source-customField/" , { formData : JSON.stringify(form)}, function(data){

       });
     });
   }
```

Then in express you access data using `req.body.formData`

```
routes.post('/add-reception-source-customField/', function(req , res){
   console.log(req.body.formData);
});
```

Comment: Ok @AmrLabib but it returns me this "name=Emp1&type=submitReceptionSourceCustomFields" ..

Comment: what is printed if you used the route i added in the answer  ?

Comment: "name=Emp1&type=submitReceptionSourceCustomFields"

Comment: Now if i use serializeArray() returns me this : [{"name":"name","value":"Emp1"},{"name":"type","value":"submitReceptionSourceCustomFields"}] . And with this I can work now! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For a HTTP POST request, the form data should be submitted in the body of the request instead of the URL.

With jQuery this would be done by passing the serialized form data as the 2nd argument to [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

```
$.post('/reception-source', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
  /* lines of code */
})
```

In express, you will want the [body-parser middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) which is maintained by the Expressjs team. This middleware will make the form data available on `req.body`...

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })

app.post('/reception-source', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    /* lines of code */
})
```

Comment: It is giving urlencoded string on server. How can I access them.